# Direct access to String Method

Tags: javascript

As we know,String methods such as **concat(),indexof()** are made available through String.prototype .So whenever new string object is created it can use those methods.But here wat i found is *String* the javascript object itself can access these methods i.e new string object are not necessarily required.How can the *String* constructor access the method present in *String.prototype*?

Working Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         var str3 = String.concat( "hlw","Stackover" );

         document.write("Concatenated String :" + str3); //outputs:hlwstackoverflow
</script>
```

And here goes the link tht shows the abv method works:Remember to replace the code with the abv one
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_76

And at last,the browser i m using is firefox

Comment: not working for me. you mean String.prototype.concat ?

Comment: typeof String.concat -> "undefined" (at least in the browser) ...

Comment: as you say it's a instance method, there's no String class with "static" methods on javascript to do that.

Comment: i have provided the link

Comment: this is not the same code

Comment: so than check with the abv code

Comment: typeof(String.concat)-> "function" in the link i provided

Comment: Your code is different. Check that in the example there are two strings variables instantiated, and then it uses one of them to do the concat.

Comment: So i m saying u to check with the abv code too..

Comment: Your code doesn't work by itself. Like I said in my answer it will only work if someone has added a method in the string main object before.  Look this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/q66g09vv/ I supose in your code, any library added a function straight to String obj.

Comment: No i have updated the code in the link u provided ,plz recheck this..http://jsfiddle.net/q66g09vv/4/

Comment: The link you've changed doesn't work for anyone but yourself. Are you using some kind of browser extension? That's no way you access this without some library, browser extension, etc... add a method to String obj

Comment: I just tested. your code works only on firefox. Like in my answer, FIREFOX BROWSER must have added a concat and some other methods straigh to String obj

Answer (score 1):

Everything (or almost everything) in Javascript is treated like an Object.

Let's suppose we are creating the String object

```
// First I will define a constructor
function String(text) {
   this.text = text;
   this.indexOf = function() { ... };
}
```

In Javascript the constructor is also an object instance. When I use "this" keyword inside a     constructor I'm telling that I want to create a new property inside a special object present in all javascript objects called **prototype**.

```
// Then I add a new property without using prototype obj
String.concat = function(txt1,txt2) { ... };

alert(String.prototype.indexOf); // it works
alert(String.concat);          // it works
                                // It will work because I'm using the String main Object
```

When you create a new instance from Myclass Obj. The new created object will inherit the  prototype object from parent, but not the properties added straight to MyClass obj:

```
var instance = new String("any text");
alert(instance.concat); // undefined because the new instance will
                     // inherit only what is inside prototype obj
```

I have to add it to the prototype object in order to new instances inherit the property;

```
String.prototype.concat = function(txt1,txt2) { ... };
var instance = new String("any text");
alert(instance.concat) // it works
```

I guess some library added a concat function straight to your String object before you calling it.

**Edit:**

Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari. Your code works on Firefox. So, I guess that FIREFOX, somewhere before you call adds a concat(txt1,txt2,...) straight to String Obj. But it's not the default behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just initiate a string object first and then concatenate like this:

```
var str = "string1"
var constr = str.concat("string2");
```

In your case:

```
var str1 = "hlw";
var str2 = "Stackover";
document.write("Concatenated String :" + str1.concat(str2));
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1txhta7f/)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method directly from the prototype like :

```
String.prototype.concat("hlw","Stackover");
```

there is no method `String.concat`, but it could happen if a 'String' variable is defined

```
var String = "";
String.concat("hlw","Stackover")
```

**But**:

This seem to be true with all Standard built-in objects in Firefox, like `Array.indexOf`

(easier to know what's happen when we know the current environment of your assumption)

BTW these methods seem to not be the same :

```
String.concat.length // 2
String.prototype.concat.length // 1
```

And the `String.concat` method is not depending on `String.prototype.concat` :

```
String.prototype.concat = null;
String.concat("foo","bar") // foobar
```

Comment: i have provided the link.